# Codeigniter not connecting to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mamp

I am currently doing the news tutorial with the codeigniter framework https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/news_section.html. But it will not connect to mysql server, the error is below.

I have granted all permissions for the user, and the config file uses the correct credentials. I am using MAMP to allow access to php and mysql servers.

Are there any preferences that I need to change to allow access through MAMP to the SQL server?

error message:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning
>
> Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 
>   'AliWalsh'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 201
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MalletManagerAPI/API/application/models/News_model.php
>   Line: 6 Function: database
>
> File: 
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MalletManagerAPI/API/application/controllers/News.php
>   Line: 7 Function: model
>
> File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MalletManagerAPI/API/index.php Line:
>   315 Function: require_once

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395300/no-db-connection-with-mamp-and-mssql-sql-server-using-codeigniter

Comment: have you added correct database credential in database.php file.

Comment: [See here for possible answer.](https://superuser.com/a/1024802) You have to reload the users table every time you change it.

Comment: If you use the username and password from your database config file to log in from the command line, does it work?

Comment: Yes I can use the credentials with the command line fine. I've also tried reloading the users table, but still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of privilege issue for the user "AliWalsh".
You can set privilege for the same user under privilege section, For this
open phpmyadmin select your database and goto privilege section,You can also change login credentials of user "AliWalsh" there

Comment: I have granted all privileges for the user on that database