# PHP PDO could'nt not find driver

Tags: php, sql-server, azure, pdo

I'm getting error of `PDO cannot find driver` using PDO in environment. I'm using xamp on a Mac.

I had got to know the problem and I've installed freetds using homebrew install, and had successfully connected to the azure mssql server using below command

```
tsql -H 234fddfg.database.windows.net -p 1433 -U dbuser -P db123!
```

but I don't know what to do next.

I've tried below php code but I'm still getting the same error.

```
$dbh = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=mydb", "dbuser", "db123");
```

Answer (score 0):

Driver for Microsoft SQL Server for PHP is needed to be installed for this.

Follow this link:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=20098

```
Perform the following steps to download and install the Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server (example below for 3.2 version):
1. Download SQLSRV32.EXE to a temporary directory
2. Run SQLSRV32.EXE
3. When prompted, enter the path to the PHP extensions directory
4. After extracting the files, read the Installation section of the SQLSRV32_Readme.htm file for next steps
```

Now just add the following line to your PHP.ini (this is for the non-thread safe version of PHP, which you are most likely using when you have installed PHP to use IIS FastCGI, which we recommend):

```
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll


And Restart server
```

Comment: You cannot run the SQLSRV extension on anything other than Windows as stated here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx

There is no where reference of mac here. Also refer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489406/sqlserv-extension-on-mac

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: Run your application on windows 7 or 8 or 8.1 or 10, whichever version of windows you have. Then install apache, php, mysql as per requirement. This is what I use as developer as it helps me developing with php and use sql server connection with php if needed.

Comment: In addition to above comment, to install Windows, If you don't want to format your machine or do not want to use another machine, you can always use virtualbox or vmware player to create windows virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed [PDO_DBLIB](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php), it seems that in OSX, we need to leverage PDO_DBLIB as the pdo driver connecting to MS SQL, e.g.

`$pdo = new PDO("dblib:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", "$dbuser","$dbpwd");`

you can refer to [Configure PHP environment on Mac to connect to SQL Server using PDO interface](https://github.com/BellevueCollege/public-docs/blob/master/PHP/configure-mssql-pdodblib-mac.md) for more information.