# Install MSSQL Driver for PHP Version 7.0.10

Tags: php, sql-server, driver

I am stuck with how to do this. I am trying to connect to a **MSSQL** database and I keep getting the error message:

> Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

So I am assuming that I need to install the driver. I am currently using **PHP Version 7.0.10.** What can I do to fix this? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

**This has been removed in PHP 7, you will need to use:**

```
sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed my code and I still get an undefined function result...`Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()`

Comment: I am also using a Mac...and from my research I think that sqlsrv is windows based.

Comment: The sqlsrv extension only works on Windows. You might find this information useful: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489406/sqlserv-extension-on-mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489406/sqlserv-extension-on-mac)